# How to avoid the text from the action link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("&nbsp","Delete", "FinancialIntermediary", 
                 new { id = item.FinancialIntermediaryID }, 
                 new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", 
                                   OnSuccess = "DeleteSuccessFI", 
                                   Confirm = "are you sure to perform the deletion." },
                 new { @class="classname" })
```

css file is

```
.classname
 {
    background-image:url('../../Images/delete.png');
 }
```

I used above code for setting the background image for delete.

By doing like this I can't avoid the text.It comes like this
[image]

I want only image on that place.Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `&nbsp;` just use a space:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ","Delete", "FinancialIntermediary", new { id = item.FinancialIntermediaryID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", OnSuccess = "DeleteSuccessFI", Confirm = "are you sure to perform the deletion." },new { @class="classname" })
```

You'd also need to make some space for your element so the background-image can be shown:

```
.classname
        {
            background-image:url('../../Images/delete.png');
            display: inline-block;
            width: 20px; /* adjust as necessary */
            height: 10px;/* adjust as necessary */ 
        }
```

Comment: @Kenneth-not working.. blankspace is coming along with the edit link

Comment: That's because the element is now to little. I have edited my answer to add the CSS

Comment: Sorry, you also need to add the height. I have edited my answer.